# Wifi on Windows 10 computer having "hiccups"

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I bought a new PC, Windows 10 and installed a TP Link wifi board in it.
Everything is working nice, I get 98% quality of signal from NetSetMan.
Speedtest gives me ~30Mb, which is what I'm paying for.

But on this PC I'm having some "hiccups", a big delay for a very short duration which is causing some trouble with gaming and streaming. There's even a game that becomes unplayable because instead of a solid 40ms from my laptop(which has Windows 7) I have it ranging 150ms-1000ms. To avoid these I stopped running OneDrive and disabled Xbox DVR, but to no avail.

My laptop doesn't seem to have those "hiccups", they are rare, even when I leave it right next to my desktop. Which leaves me thinking if it's the board's fault or Windows's fault. How can I track the problem to solve it?

Comment: Several physical factors could play: 1). Use a LAN cable. WiFi's strength is unreliable due to EMI. 2). Make sure no power cables are tangled with your LAN cable. AC power cables wrapped around anything else will act as current transformers and create resistance. 3) If 1 anf 2 don't solve your issue, check your building's connection. 30Mbps sounds like coaxial. Call your ISP and see if they can trace a wire or replace cable heads. If your cable has far to travel, many ISPs will install a line-drop compensator. Longer cables will lose more voltage towards the end.

Comment: The most harmful EMI is one that is constantly changing and inconsistent. A 110vAC at 60Hz source isn't likely to cause EMI over a LAN connection. It very well may be an old home appliance with low EMI protection or a large transformer inside the house that causes intermittent wifi.

Comment: @Shankensteinium RSSI is sitting at -50dbm, that could mean there's a ton of EMI going on right?

Comment: Between -30 dBm and -67dBm is a very good range. You'll be getting your best gaming and streaming signals in this range, though nothing is really required to have anything as good as -30 dBm for top-tier use. The awful range is anything around or less than -80 dBm (remember that these are negative numbers). If your RSSI on your host is fine, then the problem may be your router. I would still check your buildings connections first. Call a technician in and have them check your cables, cable heads, and any connections locked in their service station outside.

Comment: @Shankensteinium if I can't test my desktop with ethernet, what would you suggest? And the cables are OK, my ISP tested them a while ago and put new cable heads.

Comment: @Shankensteinium K nvm, it seems that the real problem is EMI. I used my laptop right next to the desktop cables and I noticed the same problem. Anyway I could solve it without relying to use ethernet?

Comment: If you could find the source of the EMI and eliminate it, yes. Think of the age of the building. AC units, heaters, and conduits connected to old transformers can have several changing voltages. For example, when a burner or compressor turns on periodically to satisfy a temperature setting.